# Does SonarQube still have demo site that shows analysis on major open source projects?

Tags: sonarqube

I've haven't looked at SonarQube for some time. The latest version looks quite interesting.

The last time I checked out this product, they had a site where they had pushed various popular open source libraries (like Tomcat, ActiveMQ etc) through the SonarQube process.  It was a great way of seeing how the product works.

Is this facility still available for the latest versions?

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at https://sonarcloud.io/explore/projects.

It is not a demo site - it is a globally available SonarQube server, managed by SonarSource (the company behind SonarQube). Many huge open source projects are managed there for free, but you can also host your own, private projects for closed source.

It gets updated every couple of weeks and for public releases.

---

Besides that, there is http://next.sonarqube.com , the publicly visible SonarQube server for SonarQube itself and related projects (yes: SonarQube for SonarQube).

This instance gets updated every couple of days. If you want to have a look at what features SonarQube's next version will look like: have a look there.